# vue3 setup emit with function click

Tags: vuejs3

i want to run a method when emitting how can i get it?
When `handleShow(depth` is clicked), I want to run `collapsed` in the `medhod` in the setup.
or
I want to trigger the function I will write in `setup`

```
<MenuLink
        :link="items"
        :key="items.title"
        @click.stop="handleShow(depth)"
    />
<script>
import {ref} from "vue"
import MenuLink from "./MenuLink";

export default {
  name: 'MenuItems',
  components: {MenuLink},
  props: {
    items: {type: Object, required: true},
    depth: {Number},
    selected: {Number},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      opensCollapsed: false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    collapsed(dep) {
      console.log(dep)
    }
  },
  setup(props, {emit}) {
    const showDropdown = ref(false);

    const handleShow = (depth) => {
      emit('clicked', depth)
    }
    return {
      showDropdown,
      handleShow,
    }
  },

};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`emit` should only be used if you want to get an event out of your component to its parent (for example, if your component is a custom button and you want its parent to specify what would happen when clicking on it). Otherwise, you can write the code you want inside of `handleShow` instead of calling emit. You can also change the function name to whatever you want, just make sure it's the same inside the `setup` method and in the `@click.stop` property.
In your case (since you just `console.log` the result):

```
<MenuLink
        :link="items"
        :key="items.title"
        @click.stop="handleShow(depth)"
    />
<script>
import {ref} from "vue"
import MenuLink from "./MenuLink";

export default {
  name: 'MenuItems',
  components: {MenuLink},
  props: {
    items: {type: Object, required: true},
    depth: {Number},
    selected: {Number},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      opensCollapsed: false
    };
  },
  setup(props, {emit}) {
    const showDropdown = ref(false);

    const handleShow = (depth) => {
      console.log(depth)
      // do whatever you want here
    }
    return {
      showDropdown,
      handleShow,
    }
  },

};
</script>
```

Comment: As I understand it, what he wants to do is,
When the `@click.stop="handleShow(depth)"` event fires.
`emit('clicked', depth)` makes the top component; and `showDropdown` is trying to make it true or false if the `selected` from the parent component and the depth are equal to each other.

Comment: insufficient code